# Compiling a set of Java files inside a directory tree with the JSR 199 Compiler API

Tags: java, java-compiler-api, jsr199

I'm trying to compile many files using the Compiler API.

Say I have a directory structure

> ```
> .../program
>    +/org
>     +/foo
>     |+ Main.java
>     +/bar
>      + Tools.java
> ```

Is there any way to discover all the Java files and make it compiler everything without resorting to recursing into all the directories and finding all the *.java files?

EDIT: What I'm trying to do is compile all the classes that I get in some directory tree. These classes are independent of each other. Then I load the classes and instantiate some objects of these classes and call methods. None of the classes need to have main.

Comment: It's funny that nobody's able (willing?) to help you with such a basic problem - take away the shiny IDEs and everybody will be screwed! :D

Comment: BCEL or ASM might help. http://chaoticjava.com/posts/jakartas-bcel-vs-objectwebs-asm/

Comment: The OP is talking about using the Java Compiler API aka JSR 199, not javac. It's not that basic.

Comment: Thanks fir the edit Pascal. I should have put that in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `javax.tools.JavaFileManager` class has a [`list()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaFileManager.html#list%28javax.tools.JavaFileManager.Location,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set,%20boolean%29) method that should do the trick:

```
Iterable<JavaFileObject> list(JavaFileManager.Location location,
                              String packageName,
                              Set<JavaFileObject.Kind> kinds,
                              boolean recurse)
                              throws IOException
```

Use the `recurse` parameter to include "subpackages" and then just iterate over the returned `JavaFileObject`.